# How to implement flash in cordova 2.7.0?

Tags: flash, cordova

i am beginner in android development and building some sample examples on cordova 2.7.0.
How to implement flash in cordova 2.7.0? Please provide me example of end-to-end implementation, if possible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean Adobe Flash? Flash is added to a Cordova app the same way it is in an HTML page, but Adobe Flash is *not* supported in many devices now. You should avoid using it - both in mobile web pages and Cordova as well.

Comment: Can you provide me any example url?

Comment: Again, the code to embed a Flash swf is *no* different. Simply use the embed tag.